# Object is not been read node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, filter

I have and object `db_parsed`

when I run `console.log(JSON.stringify(db_parsed, null, 4))`

the result is:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "name": "Me",
                "age": 23,
                "sex": "M"
            },
            {
                "name": "Wonderwoman",
                "age": 22,
                "sex": "F"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "name": "ALbert The Man",
                "age": 22,
                "sex": "M"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "name": "Leonard Johnson",
                "age": 23,
                "sex": "M"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

but when I run `console.log(db_parsed.data.filter(obj => obj.age === 22))`

the result is `[]`

Why? What am i missing? How do I fix this?

Comment: It's double nested, you should flatten it first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`db_parsed.data` is an array containing **arrays**.

That second level of arrays contains objects.

Your filter code is trying to treat those objects and being directly inside `db_parsed.data` instead of inside `db_parsed.data[0]`, `db_parsed.data[1]` and `db_parsed.data[2]`.

You could use `reduce` to concatenate all the second level of arrays into one, and then filter on that.

```js
var db_parsed = {
  "data": [
    [{
        "name": "Me",
        "age": 23,
        "sex": "M"
      },
      {
        "name": "Wonderwoman",
        "age": 22,
        "sex": "F"
      }
    ],
    [{
      "name": "ALbert The Man",
      "age": 22,
      "sex": "M"
    }],
    [{
      "name": "Leonard Johnson",
      "age": 23,
      "sex": "M"
    }]
  ]
};

console.log(db_parsed.data.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b), []).filter(obj => obj.age === 22))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `[].concat.apply([], db_parsed.data)` and than filter the array of objects:

```js
const db_parsed = {"data": [[{"name": "Me","age": 23,"sex": "M"},{"name": "Wonderwoman","age": 22,"sex": "F"}],[{"name": "ALbert The Man","age": 22,"sex": "M"}],[{"name": "Leonard Johnson","age": 23,"sex": "M"}]]};
const result = [].concat.apply([], db_parsed.data).filter(obj => obj.age === 22);

console.log(result);
```